# How can i retrieve the pairaddress and pairname of a given token on pancakeswap?

Tags: web3js, web3.py, pancakeswap

I'm trying to get the pairaddress and pairname of a given pancakeswap token with web3. I didn't found any solution yet. Is there a good example how to get it and which abi and contract address should i use in my eth.contract method?

Comment: You can take a look at these resources: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101630/web3-get-token-address-from-pair-address https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040453/how-to-decode-token-address-from-a-given-pair-address-in-web3

Comment: Thank you for your answer @YongjianP. but i was actually asking for the opposite way... finde the pair address of a given token and not vice versa. There are a lot of examplet how to find the token out of the factory addres but not the way around... :/

Comment: To get the token pair address you need two tokens and call getPair on the factory contract. You could get the factory address from the router calling `factory()`. See pancakeswap documentation for the details https://docs.pancakeswap.finance/code/smart-contracts/pancakeswap-exchange/router-v2#factory.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ismael that helped me a lot! But what if i don't know the second token... i mean what if i only know token0? That's the point. I know, most of the time the second token in pancakeswap is WBNB, but sometimes it can be anything... it can be BUSD or USDT... you know what i mean?

Comment: @AntonioImenes A PancakePair requires two tokens, there's no pair for a single token. It is possible with `allPairsLength` and `allPairs(uint)` to interate existing pairs. That should be done off-chain to save gas.

Comment: @Ismael thank you ... if there is no other solution rather than iterating through all of the pancake pairs then `allPairsLength` would be what i was looking for. :)